# Google Analytics (Universal) Goal Filtering

Tags: google-analytics-api

Im having a bit if an issue trying to figure out what to ask here. I assume its "how do I filter by goals in my API call" but so far my googelFu isnt showing me things I would think I would be seeing on this topic. So instead, I come with an otherwise obnoxious question:

How do I replicate what this control in the UI (see image) for google analytics is doing via API call? While yes I would like to know this, but I will also settle for the correct terminology so that I can research it myself.

I apologize if this isnt the best question but I literally do not know what I should be asking, which is part of my problem.

[image]

Comment: for the person who marked my question a needs more clarity - how am i supposed to do that? Im literally asking "what is this called" (in so many words) so I can research it.

Comment: to be clear you want to make a UI like that?  or just make a request to the API filtering on goals?

Comment: @DaimTo Well first I want to know how that drop down affects the results set, then I want to research how to do that via API. I think it is filtering by goals, but its labeled as "conversion segments." The confusion here is awkward for me as using segments requires additional setup and when i google "filter  by goal" for API examples I dont seem to fund much.